# How can I insert small icon to the side of the background url logo without messing the whole content?

Tags: html, css

As question, how can I insert small icon at the right side of the same block of background url that's is center on the page and without messing up the position of the logo (background url)? I want the logo to stay on the middle and the icon of social media at the right side of the page.

```css
.logo{
        display: block;
        text-indent: -10000px;
        background: url("http://i.imgur.com/No5YAp7.jpg") no-repeat center center;
        background-size: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 80px;
        margin: 30px auto;
    }

    #social{
        float: right;
    }

    #social ul{
        list-style: none;
    }

    #social ul li{
        display: inline-block;
        text-indent: -10000px;
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    .facebook{
        display: block;
        background: url("http://i.imgur.com/y6Y9QIs.png") no-repeat center;
        background-size: 40%;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
    }

    .instagram{
        display: block;
        text-indent: -10000px;
        background: url("http://i.imgur.com/aaDQFZ6.png") no-repeat center;
        background-size: 50%;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        margin-right: 30px;
    }
```

```html
  <h1 class="logo">abc</h1>
            
    <div id="social">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="" title="facebook" class="facebook">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="instagram" class="instagram">Instagram</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please upload the html and css in the same snippet.

Comment: alright, done!!

Comment: Would you please check your snippet? It is still not working. I suggest you to provide the full path(URL) for background images and the run the snippet. I need some visual so that I can help. If you have an image(of the layout) it'd be bonus.

Comment: Sorry about that. It should running just fine now

Answer (score 1):

Just reorder your HTML so that the social is first.

```css
.logo{
        display: block;
        text-indent: -10000px;
        background: url("http://i.imgur.com/No5YAp7.jpg") no-repeat center center;
        background-size: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 80px;
        margin: 30px auto;
    }

    #social{
        float: right;
    }

    #social ul{
        list-style: none;
    }

    #social ul li{
        display: inline-block;
        text-indent: -10000px;
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    .facebook{
        display: block;
        background: url("http://i.imgur.com/y6Y9QIs.png") no-repeat center;
        background-size: 40%;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
    }

    .instagram{
        display: block;
        text-indent: -10000px;
        background: url("http://i.imgur.com/aaDQFZ6.png") no-repeat center;
        background-size: 50%;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        margin-right: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="social">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" title="facebook" class="facebook">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="instagram" class="instagram">Instagram</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<h1 class="logo">abc</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will try it

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution is to apply `position: absolute` to your `#social` element and then position it to your liking using `top`, `right,`margin`, etc.

```css
.logo{
        display: block;
        text-indent: -10000px;
        background: url("http://i.imgur.com/No5YAp7.jpg") no-repeat center center;
        background-size: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 80px;
        margin: 30px auto;
    }

    #social{
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
    }

    #social ul{
        list-style: none;
    }

    #social ul li{
        display: inline-block;
        text-indent: -10000px;
        margin-top: 40px;
    }

    .facebook{
        display: block;
        background: url("http://i.imgur.com/y6Y9QIs.png") no-repeat center;
        background-size: 40%;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
    }

    .instagram{
        display: block;
        text-indent: -10000px;
        background: url("http://i.imgur.com/aaDQFZ6.png") no-repeat center;
        background-size: 50%;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        margin-right: 30px;
    }
```

```html
  <h1 class="logo">abc</h1>
            
    <div id="social">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="" title="facebook" class="facebook">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="instagram" class="instagram">Instagram</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this

```
#social {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: -20px;
}
```

and remove this

```
#social {
    float: right;
}
```

Here's a live example:

```css
.logo {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -10000px;
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/No5YAp7.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
#social {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  top: -15px;
}
#social ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#social ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -10000px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.facebook {
  display: block;
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/y6Y9QIs.png") no-repeat center;
  background-size: 40%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
.instagram {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -10000px;
  background: url("http://i.imgur.com/aaDQFZ6.png") no-repeat center;
  background-size: 50%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="logo">abc</h1>

<div id="social">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" title="facebook" class="facebook">Facebook</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" title="instagram" class="instagram">Instagram</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Here's another simple way of doing this**

```css
.logo, social { width: 240px; margin: 0 auto; }

 .header { max-width: 1260px; margin: 0 auto; }

 .social {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    top: 20px;
 }

a.logo_holder {
    height: 80px;
    width: 200px;
    padding: 20px 20px;
    display: block;
    background-size: 80% !important;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/No5YAp7.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}

.social li {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 ;
    text-indent: -10000px;
}

.instagram {
    display: block;
    text-indent: -10000px;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/aaDQFZ6.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size: 50%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}

.facebook {
    display: block;
    background: url(http://i.imgur.com/y6Y9QIs.png) no-repeat center;
    background-size: 40%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
<div class="logo">
 <a class="logo_holder" href="#"></a>
</div>
<div class="social">
 <ul>
    <li><a href="" title="facebook" class="facebook">Facebook</a></li>
    <li><a href="" title="instagram" class="instagram">Instagram</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```